# $L^1\big((1+x)\mathrm dx\big)$ form

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, functional-equations, integral-transforms

I am reading the [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.03588.pdf).
On page 15, they wrote

[image]

But I don't know why we can denote $\Phi(s) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{s-1}\Phi(x)dx$.

For your convenience, I also attach the picture in which there are equation (5) and kernel $k$ form $(4)$.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think that is an error in notation from the authors and that the wanted to denote the Mellin transform of $\Phi$ as something else (such as $\tilde{\Phi}$ to make notation and calculations user. The Mellin transform of $u$ should read the Mellin transform of $\omega$ (there is not $u$ function in the statement of the theorem). A change of variable will give the expression they derived for $M_\imega(t, s)$. I suggest you contact the authors directly. Their emails are in the paper which is a recent one.

Comment: @Mittens yes. I totally agree with you